# If $x$ be the AM between $y$ and $xz$, $y$ be the GM between $z$ and $x$, prove that $z$ will be the HM between $x$ and $y$.

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus

If $x$ be the AM between $y$ and $xz$, $y$ be the GM between $z$ and $x$, prove that $z$ will be the HM between $x$ and $y$.

My Attempt:

$x$ is the AM between $y$ and $xz$.
$$\textrm {AM}=\dfrac {y+xz}{2}$$
$$x=\dfrac {y+xz}{2}$$
$$2x=y+xz$$

Again,

$y$ is the GM between $z$ and $x$.
$$\textrm {GM}=\sqrt {zx}$$
$$y=\sqrt {zx}$$
$$y^2=zx$$
..

Answer (score 0):

a few calculations that might help you:
$$
zx=y^2=\bigg(x(2-z)\bigg)^2=x^2(2-z)^2
$$
if $x\ne 0$
$$
x =\frac{z}{(2-z)^2} \\
y^2 =\bigg(\frac{z}{z-2} \bigg)^2
$$

Answer (score 0):

You need to prove: $z = \dfrac{2}{\dfrac{1}{x}+\dfrac{1}{y}}\iff \dfrac{y^2}{x} = \dfrac{2xy}{x+y}= \dfrac{y^2+xyz}{x+y}= \dfrac{y^2+y^3}{x+y}= \dfrac{y^2+y^3}{\dfrac{y+y^2}{2}+y}= \dfrac{2y^2+2y^3}{3y+y^2}\iff \dfrac{1}{x} = \dfrac{2+2y}{3y+y^2}\iff 3y+y^2 = 2x + 2xy\iff 3y+y^2 = y+y^2+2xy\iff (x-1)y = 0\iff x = 1$ since $y \ne 0$. Thus $x = 1, z = 1, y = 1$, and $z$ is the HM of $x,y$.